# Making dependent functions async using promises

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions that i want to make `async` but one function is depended on another. Is it possible that both functions are `async` in nature but `function b` executes after `function a` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is a bunch of ways to do this.

If you are doing a simple callback style:

```
funcA(paramsA,function(resultsA) {
  // do some post-processing
  funcB(paramsB, function(resultsB) {
     // do some more post-processing
  });
});
```

If you are actually using promises (depends on your style and library), then it can get a bit easier:

```
funcA(paramsA).then(function(resultsA) {
  // do some post-processing
  funcB(paramsB).then(function(resultsB) {
    // do some more post-processing
  });
});
```

If you can chain promises (depends on your promises implementation):

```
funcA(paramsA).then(funcB).then(function(resultsB) { ... });
```

But the above depends on parameters being passed correctly between A and B.

My favourite is to use caolan's great async library https://github.com/caolan/async, because then you can easily do:

```
async.series([
  function(cb){funcA(paramsA).then(cb);},
  function(cb){funcB(paramsB).then(cb);}
],function(err,results) {
});
```

Or if you need the results of one from the other:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb){funcA(paramsA).then(cb);},
  function(resultsA,cb){funcB(paramsB).then(cb);}
],function(err,resultsB) {
});
```

Comment: so if my two functions are is_running() and is_saved() using promises it would be something like

funcA().then(function(resultsA) {
   is_running();
  funcB().then(function(resultsB) {
    is_saved
  });
});

is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, although you might be able to chain them, depending on the parameters from one to the other (and if your promises lib supports chaining). See the second example above.